# How to fix could not connect to host in checkout page in Joomla using Red shop

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

I am working in a Joomla website which use Red shop for his store. Everything works fine, after i update joomla to 3.5.1 the payment module Credit Card (Visa and MasterCard only) is not working.

When a user go to cart page and give the card deials and click in checkout it shows "0 Error Could not connect to host"

redshop_payment/rs_payment_scnet/rs_payment_scnet.php

Comment: Are you using latest redshop component?

Comment: yes..the redshop version is 1.5.0.6

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to open a remote URL from your application. For security reasons, many PHP instances do not allow that, and so you must ensure that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your php.ini file (note that Apache must be restarted after you enable it).

If the issue still persists, then please post the relevant content of the problematic file here.